# Why do I get non-fast-forward error in git?

Tags: git, github

I am on no branch and the only person who push currently to the stream, why when I do

```
git push
```

I get:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/dsak.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

After perform `git pull` the `git push` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no there wasn't commit on the remote that doesn't exist locally, but vice versa is correct I added files aren't in the remote to the local

You might have the same commits, but the SHA1 must have differed somehow.
That can happen if you did a rebase of master at any point (including a rebase --interactive, just to reorder or drop some commits within `master` itself).

the only other case when that error message can pop up while having the same commits (and even the same SHA1) is when you have a [conflicting *tag*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10880449/6309) (but I don't think it applies here).

Answer (score 2):

> After perform `git pull` the `git push` works just fine.

Apparently there were some commits in the remote repo that did not exist in your local repo. This could occur if you used `git reset` at some point, amended or otherwise changed existing commits (although `git pull` should've given you a warning if this was the case), or if you pushed to the remote from another repo (such as one on another computer).

Comment: no there wasn't commit on the remote that doesn't exist locally, but vice versa is correct I added files aren't in the remote to the local

Comment: @0x90: You wouldn't get that error if you only added commits to your local repo that were a direct descendant of the contents of the master branch on the remote. There were at least some commits in your local repo that were different from ones on the remote.