# rake gen_deploy rejected in Octopress

Tags: octopress

I installed Octopress in GitHub Pages.

And I clone the repository.

`$ git clone git@github.com:my-name/my-name.github.io.git`

`$ git checkout source`

And

`$ rake setup_github_pages`

I input my repository name.

And

`$ rake gen_deploy`

I got error

`! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)`

### my solution

I resolve this problem, in GitHub delete my-name.github.io.git, and make same name repository and

`$ rake gen_deploy`

### But I don't want to delete repository

What is the best solution?

Comment: There’s no need to repeat “Octopress” in the title – the context of the question is already given by the tags. In addition, Stack Overflow actually auto-adds some tags to the page title. If your title already mentions the tags, they may be displayed weirdly in the Google results (e.g. in this case as “[octopress] rake gen_deploy rejected in Octopress”).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have the same problem when hosting my Octopress blog on github pages. I Googled a lot and finally solved this problem.

Just change the directory.

```sh
cd octopress/_deploy
git pull origin master
cd ..
rake deploy
```

Then it's fixed.

Comment: Perfect - worked for me. Although I did run into merge conflicts with each file, but took the head for each file.

Answer (score 37):

**Without deleting the repository**

*Please keep in mind this is not considered best practice, but it may work for you.*

The solution is to force a push on the master branch.

Edit the `Rakefile` and look for this line:

```
system "git push origin #{deploy_branch}"
```

Alter the line by adding a plus (+) before the #{deploy_branch} tag:

```
system "git push origin +#{deploy_branch}"
```

Run the command

```
rake deploy
```

It should succeed.

**Undo the edit you made to the Rakefile!**

Idea for this solution came from reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9629458/1369730

Comment: You sir are amazing. I wish I could +1k this. I searched for 2 days on how to resolve this, and nothing else worked but this. Thank you so much!

Comment: I wasted almost 2 hrs on this but your comment saved many hours. Thanks a lot :)