# How can I commit a local git repo to existing remote repo on github through Android Studio?

Tags: git, github, android-studio, repository

I have a local project which I imported from a remote git repo to Android Studio and I am wondering how I can commit this project into my remote repo through android studio?

For what I have done;
I have been able to create a local git repo through Android Studio.

P.S: I am new to version control and I understand my question might not be very clear, I will take any corrections or guides that will help me further my understanding of VCS as well as questions to clarify my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Android Studio does not provide this functionality. I got this information from [here](http://wii.logdown.com/posts/2013/11/15/android-studio-git-tutorial) (Step 2).
These are the commands for the commandline ([See here](http://caiustheory.com/adding-a-remote-to-existing-git-repo/)):

```
git remote add origin user@host:path/to/git_repo.git
git push origin master
```

origin is just the name of the remote you're using. If you already have a remote, than origin is already in use. Just replace origin by something else. master should be replaced by your branch name.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am still having trouble after following these steps, at the push stage I get; error failed to push some refs, updates were rejected because the tip o your current branch is behind...

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713137/how-to-merge-remote-changes-at-github)? Did you connect your local repo to the matching remote repo? Seems remote has more commits than your local. Thought your remote repo is emtpy for your new project...