# Can I clear GitHub to push a rewrite?

Tags: git, github

I am using GitHub for about 1 month now, and today I found that you can't push to the GitHub repo, if the repo has folders (For me Java Packages) that the local copy does not have.

Now here is my problem: I did a rewrite of my code. I just created a new project, and started organizing everything, cleaning the code, and adding comments to make the code understandable.

**But now I can't push to GitHub, because my new (rewritten) code has 1 folder (Package) less.
Is it possible to clear my Github repo in some way, and then upload my rewrite?**

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think you are looking for a [force push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510462/force-git-push-to-overwrite-remote-files)

Comment: `git pull origin master`. first.

Comment: Don't answer your question in your question. If anything write an answer and answer your own question. Or if the question has an answer somewhere else, flag it as duplicate of that question or simply delete yours

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge remote changes at GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713137/how-to-merge-remote-changes-at-github)